# Какая структура сайта должна быть?

Tags: вёрстка

Спрашиваю потому, что в программировании стараются все систематизировать и создать определенный стиль написания. Я много излазил по интернету в поисках информации по этому вопросу и результат - все пишут как вздумается. Может это и правильно, в целях безопасности. Например, не создавать папку "adm", а вместо нее "aifjdh". Я решил переписать свой сайт и столкнулся с дилеммой, сделать правильно или как всегда. Хочется приучить себя к порядку.

Comment: Сегодня смотрел исходники одной портальной системы, запутано все донемогу. Код очень качественно написан, но сделал вывод - как бы там не путали, система всеравно попала в третьи руки и свободно можно скачать в сети, только нужно найти.

Comment: Используйте MVC фреймворки - они приучают к определённому порядку.

Comment: Не используйте фреймворков, для начала напишите пару сайтов без использования фреймворков но с использованием MVC парадигмы, чтобы потом писать правильно. Как минимум - разделять логику работы с БД и вывода, самому приятнее :)
PS:лично я сначало изучил MVC потом пописал в CI, Zend... Не понравилось, в тоге написал очень простой каркас(который помагает следовать MVC парадигме), а остальное уже пишу, подключаю, по необходимости.
Собственно не суть важно будете ли вы использовать фреймворки, важнее всего это разбиение любого кода на логические составляющие. И даже не обязательно писать ООП код..

Comment: >И даже не обязательно писать ООП код...
*facepalm*
тогда о каких логических составляющих может идти речь?

Comment: всмысле? банально:<br><br>
папка view - тут хранятся шаблоны
<br>папка model - тут скрипты для работы с БД
<br>папка controller - тут контроллеры...
<br><br>
frontControlelr тоже легко и просто пишется с использованием процедурного кода, если вы считаете что без ООП разбить код на логические состовляющие не представляется возможным это всего лишь ваше мнение, я лично работал с сайтом где использовалась MVC парадигма и весь код был написан в процедурном стиле.
<br>
PS:сам я код пишу использую ООП, я лишь написал что <b>ООП в MVC не является чемто обязательным</b><br>
Еще вопросы?

Comment: Я в джумле увидел как-то epic MVC. Файл `.../tmpl/default.php`, в нем одна строка 

    <? thisComponentController::echoHtml(); ?>

У меня теперь аллергия на джумлу)

Comment: ищем скрипт с классом thisComponentController и смотрим метод echoHtml...<br>
хотя у меня на нее тоже аллергия :D

Comment: MVC это круто - читал... Но возможно я вопрос не корректно задал...))) Я имел ввиду создание каталогов. Например для админки делают каталог adm, для гостевой gb, вопрос: для полноценного сайта с гостевой, форумом, инет магазином, какие каталоги создавать? Меня интересует полная структура и в каком каталоге что хранить. И не получится так, что этот стандарт уменьшит безопасность?

Comment: Возможно просто взять и придумать самому структуру, но тогда можно дров наломать типа графику поместить в папку css, а msql в папку forum, это я образно ... Например есть папка lib. Одни туда впихивают папки class, css, js, images другие эти папки вкладывают в папку skins. Есть ли какой-то стиль? И какой правильный? Наверно ответ получить будет трудно... Сколько людей - столько и мнений будет.

Comment: Тогда все очень просто, "защищаться" путем глупых наименований, это ИМХО примерно тоже самое что днем ездить с включеными фарами :)
<br>
Сами посудите - всеравно на сервере нужно проверять все входящие данные, права и т.д. Лично я никогда не переименовывал каталог admin например в нечто типа dsdfsfsdfsd... Т.к. я уверен в том как я обезопасил вход, если вы сильно боитесь взлома - поставьте в скрипте логина в админку sleep(10) xD<br>
В плане структуры - серверный код в своем месте, css, картинки, js в своем... Это то что для меня абсолютно очевидно, а дальше вы сами написали - сколько людей...

Comment: Спасибо... Теперь понятно, что структуры как таковой нету... Есть небольшие правила. Попробую взять структуру из MVC и ее наращивать.)))

Comment: >папка view - тут хранятся шаблоны 

>папка model - тут скрипты для работы с БД 

>папка controller - тут контроллеры...

увы, это не паттерн MVC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[[@Monsi](/users/3044/monsi)](/users/3044/monsi), защита таким образом - это не защита. Максимум можно запутать ненадолго ленивого)

На адекватных сайтах используют либо английские слова, либо их сокращения.

- /admin/
- /catalog/
- /engine/
- /images/
- /style/

Либо

- /admin/
- /cat/
- /sys/
- /img/
- /css/
- /js/

И так далее. Разрабатывать дерево каталогов нужно применимо к проекту с учетом разделения типов файлов (картинки со стилями в одну папку пихать не надо, но и для каждого js свою папку тоже не надо делать). Должно быть в первую очередь *удобно* вам, от этого и отталкивайтесь.

Comment: Я нашел в инете несколько вариантов какалогов и они отличаются друг от друга. Так как решил больше не переделывать все - разобраться, есть ли правило, но оказалось, что жестких правил нету. Всем огромное спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы посмотрел в сторону **Zend Framework**

Пусть вначале будет сложно и Очень сложно

но постепенно, все встанет на свои места

Comment: Спасибо. Постараюсь разобраться.